# Can there be a symbol for continuous product?

Tags: calculus, analysis, soft-question, terminology

We know that continuous version of $\sum$ is $\int$, but, can there be a continuous version of $\Pi$?

Comment: Equally loosely speaking, $\,\prod = e^{\sum \ln }\,$.

Comment: $e^{\int \log}?$ ${}$

Comment: Related: [What is to geometric mean as integration is to arithmetic mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/18710/856)

Comment: @dxiv That works if we product integrate a positive (or at least nonnegative) function, but the product integral is more interesting for operators (e.g. matrices) that don't commute.

Answer (score 15):

There is indeed: it is called the [product integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral).

Comment: Hah, my off-the-cuff idea [actually means something](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral#Type_I). Also, wow. (+1)

Comment: I guess there won't be any for exponentiation or tetration, right?

Comment: @ankit I'm not aware of continuous analogs for these.

Comment: @ankit I don't suppose you can define any continuum-limit if the underlying operation is not associative.