# integral for arithmetic mean-AM,GM,HM for continous distribution

Tags: definite-integrals, means

calculating arithmetic mean of a continuous distribution function is straight forward.

$AM(a,b)=\int^b_a{f(x)}dx/(b-a)$

But for GM it's harder.

Note: AM is not just for a and b ie not (a+b)/2,but all the continuous values inbetween,that's what I mean by continuous distribution, i.e. not discrete.

Comment: Posible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18710/what-is-to-geometric-mean-as-integration-is-to-arithmetic-mean

Comment: That is for generalized means, but he got without explaining...The geometric mean of yi is nothing but exp of the arithmetic mean of logyi, and this generalizes in the straightforward way to integration:
exp(∫x1x0logf(x)dx∫x1x0dx). - This is the formula's proof i need

Comment: It is not straightforward to me as the answerer says.

Comment: Although its close but not a duplicate as my question is just assumed, and not discussed

Comment: The questioner says... "Similarly, we can find the geometric mean of f(x) by taking n samples. "?? but how is my question.

Comment: The problem is products are involved and integration becomes harder

Comment: i did it this way, i had only one side and used $e^{log a\epsilon}=1+loga\epsilon$ and i get infinte products so $(dx)^2 $ or higher powers appear now i cant integrate products.